# SFMC AMPScript Lookups in Multi Org Child Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

Trying to use AMPScript to do a lookup in an email to populate various data. I'm using the synced data extension name, which because I'm using a multi org connector I'm getting this error message.

*The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
The Data Extension name for a Lookup function call is invalid. A Data Extension of this name does not exist. Data Extension Name: Contact_Salesforce Function Call: Lookup('Contact_Salesforce_4', 'FirstName', 'Id', @Id) Parameter Name: DataExtensionName Parameter Ordinal: 1*

The data extension does exist in this business unit and I have tried several variations of Contact ('Contact_Salesforce' and 'Contact') and continue to get the same error.

My code works at the enterprise level on another project and the DE of that name does exist in this business unit so this is very confusing. Anyone else experienced a similar issue when working w/ multi-org and/or child BUs.

Comment: Have you tried ent.contact_salesforce_4

Comment: I did try using that and I get a different error of "access denied". This BU is connected to a different org than the parent BU and tried several variations of the Contact DE w/ and w/out "ent." (ex. "Contact", "Contact_Salesforce", "Contact_Salesforce_4"

Comment: Is the synchronized data extension populated through a Salesforce Connection of the same business unit?

Comment: Yes, its connected to a Sales Cloud instance and is pulling in new data. Just can't figure out what to call it for MC to recognize it.